# Python namedtuple slice

Tags: python, arrays, namedtuple

this is my first question here...

if I have a namedtuple like the below

```
 FDResult = namedtuple('FDResult', ['S', 'Payoff', 'V'])
```

and I have an array that has a collection of namedtuple like the below

```
 bla = [FDResult(S=100.0, Payoff=0.0, V=0.4693541525097441),
 FDResult(S=102.0, Payoff=1.0, V=0.4944046100897207),
 FDResult(S=104.0, Payoff=1.0, V=0.5188897967596792),
 FDResult(S=106.0, Payoff=1.0, V=0.5427339609362274),
 FDResult(S=108.0, Payoff=1.0, V=0.5658731041633024)]
```

How do I get an array slice of S?

```
 bla[:].S #I want to get [100.0,102.0,104.0,...] as a result
```

that doesn't work with error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'S'...

Any suggestion appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: That's not what slicing is there for. Slicing selects a range of indices from one collection (e.g. `l[-2:]` returns a new list with the last two elements of `l`), it doesn't select attributes from its members.

Comment: `bla[:]` just gives you a copy of the list.  Slicing doesn't pluck out parts of elements; it only gives you some subset of the elements.  You want a list comprehension, as in @wim's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), for example

```
[x.S for x in bla[:]]
```

You can of course substitute a more general slice of your list in there, e.g. `bla[1:-1:2]`.

Comment: Might as well be `for x in bla`, you don't need to create a copy.

Comment: As I read it, the whole point of this question was to use a _slice_, so I left the slice in with `bla[:]` just being a general example of a slice (as the OP also used).

Comment: As I read it, the whole point was a basic misunderstanding of what a slice does. (Seeing as it's completely useless here.)